# Python 3 script using relative imports on standard input gives error: No module named '__main__.XXX'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, elpy

Python 3 script using relative imports on standard input gives error: No module named '**main**.XXX'; '**main**' is not a package

If I have a Python 3 script that uses a relative import statement of the form

```
from .subscript2 import subfunc2
```

And some other script imports the above script as a module, it works without issue. However, when I execute the script containing the above line on standard input to the Python interpreter, I get an error of the form:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.subscript2'; '__main__' is not a package
```

The reason I need to use stdin, is because I need to use Elpy (https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that allows me to evaluate that script (using the C-c C-c key binding) and then add additional Python code to call functions in that script, akin to the pdb 'interact' command.

Below is the self-contained script to demonstrate what is happening:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /tmp/topdir
mkdir /tmp/topdir
mkdir /tmp/topdir/subdir

unset PYTHONPATH

cat > /tmp/topdir/topscript.py <<'EOF'
from subdir.subscript1 import subfunc1
EOF

touch /tmp/topdir/subdir/__init__.py

cat > /tmp/topdir/subdir/subscript1.py <<'EOF'
from .subscript2 import subfunc2

def subfunc1():
    subfunc2()

print('subscript1 loaded successfully')
EOF

cat > /tmp/topdir/subdir/subscript2.py <<'EOF'
import os
def subfunc2():
    print('subfunc2 called. Current working directory: {}'.format(os.getcwd()))

print('subscript2 loaded successfully')
subfunc2()
EOF

echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Python version:
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python --version

cd /tmp
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Direct execution of topscript.py from inside $(pwd)
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python /tmp/topdir/topscript.py

cd /tmp/topdir
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Using stdin on topscript.py from inside $(pwd):
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python < topscript.py

cd /tmp/topdir/subdir
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Using stdin on subscript1.py from inside $(pwd):
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python < subscript1.py

cd /tmp/topdir/subdir
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Using -m subscript1 from inside $(pwd):
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python -m subscript1

cd /tmp/topdir/subdir
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Using stdin on subscript2.py from inside $(pwd):
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python < subscript2.py

# This one was added in response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55895684/257924
cd /tmp/topdir
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Using -m on subdir.subscript1 from inside $(pwd):
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
python -m subdir.subscript1

# This one is a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55895684/257924 using symlinks:
cd /tmp/topdir/subdir
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo "Using -m on selfdir.subscript1 from inside $(pwd) (where selfdir is a symlink):"
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ln -s ../subdir selfdir
python -m selfdir.subscript1
```

Here is the output of the above:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Python version:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Python 3.7.3

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Direct execution of topscript.py from inside /tmp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp
subscript1 loaded successfully

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using stdin on topscript.py from inside /tmp/topdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir
subscript1 loaded successfully

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using stdin on subscript1.py from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.subscript2'; '__main__' is not a package

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using -m subscript1 from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drunkard/conda/Ubuntu.18.04.miniconda3/envs/envpython3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/drunkard/conda/Ubuntu.18.04.miniconda3/envs/envpython3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/topdir/subdir/subscript1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .subscript2 import subfunc2
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using stdin on subscript2.py from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir/subdir

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using -m on subdir.subscript1 from inside /tmp/topdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir
subscript1 loaded successfully

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using -m on selfdir.subscript1 from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir (where selfdir is a symlink):
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir/subdir
subscript1 loaded successfully
```

I've tried various things and could not come up with a solution. The best I could do is delete the initial "." like this:

```
from subscript2 import subfunc2
```

but it breaks normal execution:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Python version:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Python 3.7.3

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Direct execution of topscript.py from inside /tmp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/topdir/topscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subdir.subscript1 import subfunc1
  File "/tmp/topdir/subdir/subscript1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subscript2 import subfunc2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subscript2'

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using stdin on topscript.py from inside /tmp/topdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/topdir/subdir/subscript1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subscript2 import subfunc2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subscript2'

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using stdin on subscript1.py from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir/subdir
subscript1 loaded successfully

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using -m subscript1 from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir/subdir
subscript1 loaded successfully

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using stdin on subscript2.py from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir/subdir

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using -m on subdir.subscript1 from inside /tmp/topdir:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drunkard/conda/Ubuntu.18.04.miniconda3/envs/envpython3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/drunkard/conda/Ubuntu.18.04.miniconda3/envs/envpython3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/topdir/subdir/subscript1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subscript2 import subfunc2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subscript2'

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using -m on selfdir.subscript1 from inside /tmp/topdir/subdir (where selfdir is a symlink):
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
subscript2 loaded successfully
subfunc2 called. Current working directory: /tmp/topdir/subdir
subscript1 loaded successfully
```

In order to make the above work, I would have to set `PYTHONPATH` in the environment to the colon-separated list of the directories with all of the scripts I use. That would work, for my own scripts, but just as soon as I want to read other published scripts into python via stdin, it will break again unless I go through those scripts and delete the initial "." temporarily (which is a hassle and error-prone).

So, is there a way to make this work for all of those cases?  I do have the option to change the tool I'm using (the one that feeds the script to python's stdin) to add additional code to that stdin stream,  *before* the actual script, but if that is the solution, what statements would force it to work?

Helpful reference material to aid in understanding, but that did not reveal the solution:

- [intra-package-references](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8195271/257924
- The Imports section of https://hackaday.com/2018/08/15/stop-using-python-2-what-you-need-to-know-about-python-3/
- https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/257924

Comment: seems you're trying to execute a _package_ as a script, I'd suggest instead invoking with `python -m` which will have the most predictable import semantics

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` in the folder you are importing? Sometimes that is the issue

Comment: @DanielButler I neglected to mention that I have tried it both with, and without, a zero-length `/tmp/topdir/subdir/__init__.py` file, and it had no effect on the problem.

Comment: @AnthonySottile I just now updated the question to demonstrate invoking with `python -m`. It gives a different error there, so was that you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time looking at clever alternatives to allow me to do what I want, and all of the solutions I could think of were just too complicated to put into practice, so:

I ended up avoiding this by using symbolic links in the same directory in which the top-level script resides. It's not great, but its better than having to change PYTHONPATH in the working environment. So if I have utility modules stored in my ~/bin/python directory, but I'm actually working on a script in, say, ~/some_project_dir/my_top_level.py, I create a symbolic link like this:

```
ln -s ~/bin/python ~/some_project_dir/python
```

then inside the my_top_level.py file, I use import statements such as:

```py
from python.file_utils import read_lines_from_file
lines = read_lines_from_file("/tmp/some_file")
```

So if I ever relocate ~/some_project_dir to some other directory, the symbolic link goes with it. If I ever were to move the ~/bin/python directory, then I do have the chore of updating the symbolic links, but that is a minor chore, and doesn't happen all that much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-m subdir.subscript1` from within `topdir`. The `subdir` folder is a package, and when you use `-m` you need to give a fully qualified name to the module you want to run, or it can't figure out that it's supposed to be part of a package rather than a top-level module.

Try this:

```
echo
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo Using -m on subscript1.py:
echo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
cd /tmp/topdir                        # note, changed folder here
python -m subdir.subscript1           # add package name prefix here
```

Comment: This answer is indeed helpful. I've the script in my question to do what you suggested and it does help with loading. However, note how I am now printing out the current working directory as seen from `subfunc2`.  But, in the read-eval-print loop style of development, I will often have files in the same current working directory as the `subscript2.py` file, that the script will want to read with something like `with open('localfile', 'r') as f: ...`.  And so that style of development will be thwarted, and I'll have to be calling `os.chdir()` in my script to work around that.

Comment: As an experiment, I updated my question to create a symbolic link called "selfdir" that points back to the very same directory.  Then, the current working directory can be that same directory where the script is in, allowing the read-eval-print loop style of development to continue to work.  Now, if I can arrange for that link to be created on the fly so to speak, then that might be a solution.  But that a major kludge workaround.

Comment: To open files from the same folder as a module, I'd not mess around with how the imports work, but instead use the `__file__` global variable to get access to the path to the module file, then split it up to get a usable path to `subdir`. Something like `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'localfile')`.

Comment: After some experimentation, I came to the realization that using `-m` option with any module is not going to work in this case with `elpy` as it needs to read the script from standard input.  And `-m` implies that the functions in the .py file will no longer be at the top-level, but be in the scope of whatever is fed to the `-m`.  So although this is helpful to see the possibilities, it isn't what I'm after.

Comment: In that situation, one idea might be to put the "real" code in some file somewhere in the search path (perhaps in a package, where you can do relative imports), and have the "script" that you pass in via stdin be just `import some_package.some_module` and `some_package.some_module.main()`.

Comment: That might be viable. The key constraint in my case is to keep the user's focus inside the module that is being edited and not have to flip over to some other module just so as to run it from there. That is to avoid distracting the user during development. But there might be a way to customize `elpy` to make it work. I'll have to experiment.